# how to click on button Add to add in another row with a list of textbox that will appear?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

i am using asp.net and vb.net
in my student.aspx have a row of text box something like below

```
class       name        registerNo 
txtClass    txtName     txtRegisterNo      btnAdd

btnSubmit
```

so what am i going to use to add in a new row with txtClass    txtName     txtRegisterNo      after i click on the button and when click on submit each new row of textbox value enter will be insert into the database

it is something like this after i click on the btnAdd, if it continue to click on btnAdd another row with the textbox will appear

```
class       name        registerNo 
txtClass    txtName     txtRegisterNo      
txtClass    txtName     txtRegisterNo      btnAdd
```

so what should i use to do achieve this result? or what code should i add in the student.aspx.vb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be is to use a repeater control from asp.net. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx). There are multiple options. You can also use jQuery along with client side controls. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)